# filetype is set differently for first buffer and split buffer

Tags: vim

Today I encountered very strange behaviour in vim. When I open a python file some things are automatically setup p.ex. `expandtab`. If I open a second python file with `:sp` then `expandtab` is not set, while `filetype=python` seems to be correct.

I removed `.vim` and stripped down my `.vimrc` to:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

With the help of `verbose set filetype?` I could figure out:

- first buffer: Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
- split buffer: Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/scripts.vim

Why is this different and how could I fix it?

(I'm using vim version: 2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3)

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at your full setup.  This might be the result of an incorrect `autocmd`, a plugin, an overly enthusiastic ftplugin, or any number of other tiny Vim pitfalls.

Comment: The only thing I setup is the mentioned line in .vimrc

Comment: To get a "clean slate" Vim: `vim -u <your_simplified_vimrc> -i NONE -N --noplugin`

Comment: hmm, ok. now I get `scripts.vim` for both cases, but the issue is still there.

Comment: That's odd, because it should be `filetype.vim`, rather than `scripts.vim`.

Comment: scripts.vim inspects first line of file and `set ft=python` while filetype.vim defines an autocmd on *.py and `setf python`. I'm not an vim expert, any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps ask on the vim_dev list?  SO is not the best place to debug this, you know.